# Permission to stay home by doctor because of having an illness

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

What is the name of the paper that a doctor writes for someone letting his/her school, workplace, etc know that he/she has been sick for a period of time and needs to rest (off from work or school)?

Comment: "Doctor's note" is the one I've most commonly heard in semi-formal contexts.

Comment: Side note (not really a full answer) - when I read "allowance", I thought you were talking about "money", rather than "permission".

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It may also be called simply a **doctor's note**, being the most succinct description of what it is - a short note from a doctor explaining the person is unfit for work.

Comment: "Doctor's note" or "note from the doctor" are the most common ways to refer to this kind of document in the US.

Comment: They are likewise the most common names for this sort of thing in the UK.

Comment: Any source stating the same would be helpful.

Answer (score 7):

It's called a [medical certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medical_certificate), or simply "doctor's certificate".

This certificate "attests to the result of a medical examination of a patient". Note that the result of the aforesaid examination can declare the examinee either fit or unfit.

The "sick note" is a "documentation that an employee is unfit for work", i.e., he/she is really sick.

Comment: isn't `medical certificate` given to someone who has completed medial school?

Comment: That'd be a `medical degree`. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medical_degree

Comment: there is a phrase (`sick note`) in the link you have provided. I assume it is the informal synonym for `medical certificate`, right?

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani yes.

Comment: Where is the phrase "doctor's certificate" used? I'm in the US and I don't think I've ever heard that phrase used.

Comment: @TannerSwett If you see the references on the Wikipedia article, you'll find the following two use cases (both Australian): http://workplaceinfo.com.au/payroll/leave/news/employers-should-not-question-a-doctors-certificate-ama and https://www.medicalobserver.com.au/professional-news/doctor-s-certificate-questioned-after-mp-skips-parliament

Comment: Please [don't use](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28/should-backticks-be-used-or-quotation-marks-while-formatting) `code markup` for emphasis. *Italics* (or just plain "quotes") would be far more appropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

In a private school in the UK, it might be called an [exeat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exeat) — Latin for “he may leave”.

Comment: No, that's the permission slip to allow a pupil to go out of school, for example for a doctor's appointment.

Comment: It would be helpful to include a summary for the relevant bits from your link. Linked material can change or become inaccessible, and we would rather have the complete answer here instead of pushing our visitors off to Wikipedia.